# TabBarController: accessing a property of inside UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, tabs

I am working on an app with three tabs.
From first tab, I want to access variables which happen to be defined as @property inside tab # 3 [- defined by SettingsViewController].

I added the below import line to the header file of the first tab:

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
```

My SettingsViewController header has IBOutlet as below:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *username;
```

From implementation inside the first tab I call:

```
    NSLog(@"Figuring out how to access the Settings view %@", self.tabBarController.viewControllers[2]);
```

It correctly points to the right object, printing out:

```
2014-08-11 14:46:12.700 backup[30043:60b] Figuring out how to access the Settings view <SettingsViewController: 0x8db2020>
```

The below however does not work:

```
self.username = (SettingsViewController *)self.tabBarController.viewControllers[2].username;
```

I get an XCode static code analyzer error: property 'username' not found on object of type 'id'

What is the proper Objective-C way of casting id type to the what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix your parenthesis. Currently it is evaluating "self.tabBarController.viewControllers[2].username" and then doing the cast

This should work:

```
self.username = ((SettingsViewController *)self.tabBarController.viewControllers[2]).username;
```